# How to create more gap between axis labels on a stacked bar chart?

Tags: css, highcharts

I've recreated my problem in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FYs3q/

My categories I'm putting on the left side of the bar chart are dynamic and put into the categories list:

```
xAxis: {
categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Orangesa', 'Pearsa',
'Grapesa', 'Bananasa', 'Orangess', 'Pearss', 'Grapess', 'Bananass', 'Orangesd', 'Pearsd',
'Grapesd', 'Bananasd', 'Orangesf', 'Pearsf', 'Grapesf', 'Bananasf', 'Orangesg', 'Pearsg',
'Grapesg', 'Bananasg', 'Orangesr', 'Pearsr', 'Grapesr', 'Bananasr', 'Orangese', 'Pearse',
'Grapese', 'Bananase', 'Orangesw', 'Pearsw', 'Grapesw', 'Bananasw', 'Orangesq', 'Pearsq',
'Grapesq', 'Bananasq', 'Orangesy', 'Pearsy', 'Grapesy', 'Bananasy', 'Orangesu', 'Pearsu',
'Grapesu', 'Bananasu', 'Orangesi', 'Pearsi', 'Grapesi', 'Bananasi']
}
```

When they get to a certain amount they just start squishing up against each other, and eventually they get lost. Ideally, the bar chart would just keep getting bigger in height rather than these labels getting squished up against each other.

The problem goes away if I make the chart big enough to handle all of the categories, but it feels like there should be a way to set a padding amount on these labels and the size would be figured out dynamically, but I've been through the entire API and there hasn't been a setting that works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a built in method to dynamically increase the chart size based on the number of elements.

I handle this server side in most cases.  I establish a 'base height' to account for top and bottom margins.  Then I define a multiplier, set to the height needed for each element.

Then I count my data array, multiply by the multiplier, and add the base, and echo it as the height of the chart's containing div.

You could certainly handle this in javascript as easily by modifying the containing element's height after establishing the data, and before calling the chart.

Working `example`:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/9AWsX/

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a way to set that padding number but this solution does the trick nicely.